# Rooks on chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image: quiestion]

When I look from this perspective: My first choise ist n^2*(n-1)^2*...*1^2. The explanation is that, first i can choose from n times n position, when i have chosen one it "blocks" 1 row and 1 column. 
Okey obviously buy choosing my way I have n-Vector, and rooks are the same so i have to divide by n! The result would be n! And now my question if I had choosen allready a 1-set from NxN: 
$\binom{n^2}{1}*\binom{(n-1)^2}{1}*...*\binom{1^2}{1}$ I dont see thats is the same as n! Where is my mistake? I am counting something else, but i dont know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last expression is equal to $(n!)^2$.  In the sentences leading up to it you justify that this should be divided by $n!$.  It is generally true that ${a \choose 1}=a$ so the last expression is the same as your first.  You just failed to divide by the $n!$

Comment: How ${a\choose 1}=1$ ? Or should it be $a$?

Comment: @AtulMishra:  yes, it is a typo.  Thanks

Comment: Im sorry but
$$\binom{a}{1}=a}$$ The binomial coefficient gives the number of k-sets. They have no order, since they are sets. The second thing is you cant do that: (2^3)! is not equal to (2!)^3. So my second product opens to (n^2)!*((n-1)^2)!*.... p.s. i dont know whats wrong with latex in comments.

Comment: Extra brace @thetha

Comment: @thetha:  I fixed the first.  No, you second product gives the same $n^2 \cdot (n-1)^2 \cdot (n-2)^2 \ldots 1^2=(n!)^2$.  MathJax works fine in comments but you don't get a preview.  In your case you have an extra brace at the end.

Comment: @RossMillikan okey, i think i get it! By choosing one by one, i get the "order" of Elements